# Android - Change inflated layout height programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on changing the height of a layout programatically.

Here's a snippet of the layout initialization :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View pagerItemInflater = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        LayoutResize layoutResize = new LayoutResize();

RelativeLayout relativeViewPager =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeViewPager);
        int relativeViewPagerHeight = layoutResize.height(75, displayMetrics);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewPagerParams = relativeViewPager.getLayoutParams();
        viewPagerParams.height = relativeViewPagerHeight;
        relativeViewPager.setLayoutParams(viewPagerParams);

        RelativeLayout viewPagerItem =(RelativeLayout) pagerItemInflater.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerItem);
        int viewPagerItemWidth = layoutResize.width(100, displayMetrics);
        int viewPagerItemHeight = layoutResize.height(28, displayMetrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewPagerItemParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(viewPagerItemWidth, viewPagerItemHeight);
        //ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewPagerItemParams = viewPagerItem.getLayoutParams();
        viewPagerItemParams.height = viewPagerItemHeight;
        viewPagerItem.setLayoutParams(viewPagerItemParams);
```

The problem is, I can't get the second one which is `viewPagerItem` to resize to 28% of screen. When I use log, the viewPagerItemHeight shows the appropiate height I wanted, but the layout doesn't resize as expected.

I've read around and some people said that `View pagerItemInflater = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);` null is supposed to be the root class right? The `R.layout.activity_main`? But I can't use it there, it says `cannot resolve method inflate(int,int)`

Comment: It is NOT inflate(int, int), it is inflate(int, ViewGroup)

Comment: So what should I do? Add my `activity_main` to ViewGroup?

Comment: first of all, remove the first line (setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);) and add this in the end setContentView(pagerItemInflater);

Comment: You mean I change the layout to my image pager? It shows `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.widget.RelativeLayout.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Well sure it gives you NPE because findViewById(R.id.relativeViewPager) returns null. I didnt notice those findViewById calls... Try placing the setContentView(pagerItemInflater); under the View pagerItemInflater = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); line.

Comment: I've placed it under that, still NPE, because the `relativeViewPager` now contains my main layout, not the relativeViewPager layout??